# Thread-safe mutable non-owning pointer in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to parallelize an algorithm I have. This is a sketch of how I would write it in C++:

```
void thread_func(std::vector<int>& results, int threadid) {
   results[threadid] = threadid;
}

std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> results(4);

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     spawn_thread(thread_func, results, i);
  }

  join_threads();

  return results;
}
```

The point here is that each thread has a reference to a shared, mutable object that it does not own. It seems like this is difficult to do in Rust. Should I try to cobble it together in terms of (and I'm guessing here) `Mutex`, `Cell` and `&mut`, or is there a better pattern I should follow?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644152/processing-vec-in-parallel-how-to-do-safely-or-without-using-unstable-features ?

Comment: See also: https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool

Comment: I think the rust book covers exactly that case here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/concurrency.html#safe-shared-mutable-state

Comment: See also my response for a similar question which uses pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608015/parallel-computing-of-array-elements-in-rust/31609380#31609380

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to use `Arc<Mutex<...>>` or, for example, `Arc<RWLock<...>>`. `Arc` is a shared ownership-based concurrency-safe pointer to immutable data, and `Mutex`/`RWLock` introduce synchronized internal mutability. Your code then would look like this:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn thread_func(results: Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>, thread_id: i32) {
    let mut results = results.lock().unwrap();
    results[thread_id as usize] = thread_id;
}

fn foo() -> Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>> {
    let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![0; 4]));

    let guards: Vec<_> = (0..4).map(|i| {
        let results = results.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || thread_func(results, i))
    }).collect();

    for guard in guards {
        guard.join();
    }

    results
}
```

This unfortunately requires you to return `Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>` from the function because there is no way to "unwrap" the value. An alternative is to clone the vector before returning.

However, using a crate like [scoped_threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) (whose approach could only be recently made sound; something like it will probably make into the standard library instead of the now deprecated [`thread::scoped()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) function, which is unsafe) it can be done in a much nicer way:

```
extern crate scoped_threadpool;

use scoped_threadpool::Pool;

fn thread_func(result: &mut i32, thread_id: i32) {
    *result = thread_id;
}

fn foo() -> Vec<i32> {
    let results = vec![0; 4];
    let mut pool = Pool::new(4);

    pool.scoped(|scope| {
        for (i, e) in results.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            scope.execute(move || thread_func(e, i as i32));
        }
    });

    results
}
```

If your `thread_func` needs to access the whole vector, however, you can't get away without synchronization, so you would need a `Mutex`, and you would still get the unwrapping problem:

```
extern crate scoped_threadpool;

use std::sync::Mutex;

use scoped_threadpool::Pool;

fn thread_func(results: &Mutex<Vec<u32>>, thread_id: i32) {
    let mut results = results.lock().unwrap();
    result[thread_id as usize] = thread_id;
}

fn foo() -> Vec<i32> {
    let results = Mutex::new(vec![0; 4]);
    let mut pool = Pool::new(4);

    pool.scoped(|scope| {
        for i in 0..4 {
            scope.execute(move || thread_func(&results, i));
        }
    });

    results.lock().unwrap().clone()
}
```

But at least you don't need any `Arc`s here. Also `execute()` method is `unsafe` if you use stable compiler because it does not have a corresponding fix to make it safe. It is safe on all compiler versions greater than 1.4.0, according to its build script.

Comment: It'd be nice if someone added a link to a pull request into the Rust compiler which fixes the bug which prevents making `execute()` safe on the stable channel (see the last paragraph).

Comment: Could I do something like `Arc<Mutex<  &mut 'a Vec<i32>>>`, so that I didn't have to return an `Arc<Mutex<...>>`?

Comment: No, you can't. That's the whole point of scope-based API actually. You can't move data with borrowed references inside it into `thread::spawn()` because it may be unsafe - you could forget to join with the spawned thread, and the references could become invalid. With scoped API the join is enforced statically, and therefore you can share a reference and do not need `Arc`s.