# One mutable borrow and multiple immutable borrows

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, ownership

I'm trying to write a program that spawns a background thread that continuously inserts data into some collection. At the same time, I want to keep getting input from `stdin` and check if that input is in the collection the thread is operating on.

Here is a boiled down example:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut set: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            set.insert("foo".to_string());
        }
    });

    loop {
        let input: String = get_input_from_stdin();

        if set.contains(&input) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}

fn get_input_from_stdin() -> String {
    String::new()
}
```

However this doesn't work because of ownership stuff.

I'm still new to Rust but this seems like something that should be possible. I just can't find the right combination of `Arc`s, `Rc`s, `Mutex`es, etc. to wrap my data in.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312045/how-can-multiple-threads-share-an-iterator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread-safe mutable non-owning pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249817/thread-safe-mutable-non-owning-pointer-in-rust)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, please read [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674479/need-holistic-explanation-about-rusts-cell-and-reference-counted-types/45674912).

---

There are two problems to solve here:

1. Sharing ownership between threads,
2. Mutable aliasing.

To share ownership, the simplest solution is `Arc`. It requires its argument to be `Sync` (accessible safely from multiple threads) which can be achieved for any `Send` type by wrapping it inside a `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

To safely get aliasing in the presence of mutability, both `Mutex` and `RwLock` will work. If you had multiple readers, `RwLock` might have an extra performance edge. Since you have a single reader there's no point: let's use the simple `Mutex`.

And therefore, your type is: `Arc<Mutex<HashSet<String>>>`.

The next trick is passing the value to the closure to run in another thread. The value is *moved*, and therefore you need to *first* make a clone of the `Arc` and then pass the clone, otherwise you've moved your original and cannot access it any longer.

Finally, accessing the data requires going through the borrows and locks...

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let set = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashSet::new()));

    let clone = set.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            clone.lock().unwrap().insert("foo".to_string());
        }
    });

    loop {
        let input: String = get_input_from_stdin();

        if set.lock().unwrap().contains(&input) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `unwrap` is there because `Mutex::lock` returns a `Result`; it may be impossible to lock the `Mutex` if it is poisoned, which means a panic occurred while it was locked and therefore its content is possibly garbage.

Comment: As the [`Mutex` "Trait Implementations"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#implementations) documents you cannot wrap *any* type to get `Sync`; you need to wrap a `Send` type.

Comment: @Stefan: Right! I didn't even think about someone trying to send a non-Send type to another thread, but it's definitely better to be explicit about it.